# Add spring message to html attribute placeholder

Tags: html, spring-mvc, localization, internationalization

I am trying to add a message to an html attribute "placeholder" and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251010/spring-locale-messages-dont-work-only-within-springform-tag) which is working fine for english messages but not for greek messages (UTF-8 encoding).

```
<spring:message code="label.message" var="messagePlace" htmlEscape="true" />
<td class="textfield"><form:textarea id="message_box"               
class="field" path="message" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="${messagePlace}" />
```

Every other message is successfully resolved. The default encoding of the application is UTF-8. Any ideas? The text I get is "& Mu;ή& nu;& upsilon;& mu;& alpha;" (without the spaces) instead of "Μήνυμα".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I see this is because the element form:textarea of the form tag library of spring does not support the attribute placeholder. When using an html textarea the message appears correctly.